# Is there C language documentation on Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, c, documentation

Is there a package on Debian or some other Linux media that provides documentation for the C language? I mean in particular `man` pages. Eg. so that I can check docs for `typedef` or other basics (and possibly advanced concepts).